# Modify SpeakHere to record audio played on device

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

Could someone explain to me how I could modify Apple's SpeakHere iPhone sample code to record audio being played on the device rather than audio being inputted through the mic.

Answer (score 2):

you cant access the audio played from the ipod, there is nothing that you can use in apples libraries to get access to the ipod output. i assume this is the audio you refer to. copyright issues etc.

Answer (score 0):

actually  I am not sure this is true.  Look into aurioTouch.  I asked a question like this once and someone referred me to it